# how to conduct blackjack simulation with replacement

Tags: r, statistics, simulation

how would I Write code to simulate 5,000 repetitions of 2 cards being dealt to a player, whereby the cards are drawn with replacement. Using the relative freq of of a blackjack incidence In 5,000 repetitions of two cards being drawn (example; at a casino), provide an estimate of the prob of attaining a blackjack.
Ive tried something like this:

```
set.seed(5000)
handValue = function(cards) {
  value = sum(cards)
  
       # Check for an Ace and change value if it doesn't bust
  if (any(cards == 1) && value <= 11) 
    value = value + 10
  
       # Check bust (set to 0); check Blackjack (set to 21.5)
  if(value > 21)  
    0 
  else if (value == 21 && length(cards) == 2)  
    21.5 # Blackjack
  else 
    value
}
```

But I'm not sure how to exactly simulate with replacement and this code was some rough ideas so it may be well off the mark.

Answer (score 0):

How to simulate drawing 2 cards without replacement

```
sample(c(1:9,rep(10,4)),2,replace=F)
```

**Edit**: with replacement

```
sample(c(1:9,rep(10,4)),2,replace=T)
```

**Edit2**: example with 5 replications

```
replicate(5,{sample(c(1:9,rep(10,4)),2,replace=T)})
```

Comment: I edited the question, I'm looking for a simulation with replacement

Comment: How would I simulate 5,000 repetitions of 2 cards being dealt to a player in the blackjack context?